# AutoIT send() commands not working properly

Tags: scripting, automation, autoit, game-development

So I have a game client with 2 input fields: id pass and 1 button: login.
My login credentials are: `$id=1234` and `$pass=a_bCd`.
I'm using AutoIT scripting to automate the login process (my script automatically inputs the id and pass in the login fields) and my `AutoLogin()` function looks like:

```
send($id + "{tab}")
Sleep(10)
send($pass + "{enter}")
```

Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes my script introduces `1234a-` or `1234a_` in the ID field and the rest of the characters in the pass field. I tried many solutions like `controlsend("Game","","","1234{tab}a_bCd{enter}")`, or changing `sleep()` values, etc. but the input still goes wrong sometimes. Figured the send delay or sleep would have the problem, still don't know what to do.

Manually inserting the id and pass works properly. What would be a good solving of this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same troubles with `send`. [This post](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/157677-send-key-problem/?do=findComment&comment=1143051) on autoitscript.com may help you with `WinAPI_Keybd_Event()` ([documentation here](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_WinAPI_Keybd_Event.htm)):

```
#include <WinAPISys.au3>
_WinAPI_Keybd_Event(0x11, 0) # Push CTRL down
_WinAPI_Keybd_Event(0x11, 2) # Lift CTRL up again
```

This helped me with my problems.

NOTE: Sometimes, when your script breaks because of an error, it may happen that one of the keys on your keyboard is still pressed (i.e. pushed down but never lifted up). I use the on-screen keyboard that is integrated in Windows for these moments...

Answer (score 0):

2 Solutions:

You add Strings with &:

```
send($id & "{tab}")
send($pass & "{enter}")
```

If that does not work just separate it:

```
send($id)
send("{tab}")
send($pass)
send("{enter}")
```

And you don't need that sleep